# First coding project: website launches locally from VS Code, but not from Git Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, git-push

I'm struggling with my first little coding project of HTML, CSS, and JS. On the VS code locally, the website looks as intended [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ZAS.png)
However when deploying it via git pages, it looks like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3jwZ.png)
My VS code and git repository match in terms of file location, so I'm not sure why the console can't find the other files [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXQgt.png)

Here is a link to my repository https://github.com/l-antonello/prework-study-guide
and the site https://l-antonello.github.io/prework-study-guide/

Thanks, any advice would be appreciated.

So I tried pushing and pulling from VS Code to github and sometimes it would work, but I think I had too many folder desitnations? So then I just manually uploaded the code pages, I know thats not the best way of going about it, which is why I have so many commits lol.

I also had an issue of the README publishing instead of the HTML, but moving it to another folder seemed to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the link to the style file wrong, currently is like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
```

And it should be like this by checking your folder structure:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prework-study-guide/assets/style.css">
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much I really appreciate it; it seems so simple now! I'm having the same issue with my png, but it should be straightforward if it's like the pathway issue.

Comment: Nice to see it worked, if you found it useful, remember to set this answer as correct.